# qtextbrowser align right or center

Tags: python, html, qt, pyqt

I was trying to make some kind of help system for my application. QTextBrowser and a static HTML file seemed perfect for me. Only thing is that QTextBrowser is not reading alignment correctly - everything is aligned left.

My HTML file is one big borderless table with some rows aligned center, others left or right. I could post the whole file, but there is no point, here is the code for one row with one cell; other cells are just copy/paste.

```
<tr align="center">
  <td><img src="10.png"></img></td>
</tr>
```

That image should be centered, but it's not. Whole page looks good in both Chromium and Firefox, only QTextBrowser is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QTextBrowser` widget only has support for limited [subset of html/css](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/richtext-html-subset.html).

In this particular case, the `tr` tag has no support for the `align` attribute, but the `td` and `th` tags do (see the [table cell attributes](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/richtext-html-subset.html) section for the complete list).

Comment: Thank you again ekhumoro, will try it ASAP. I checked that link prior to making this question, but I guess I needed a fresh pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at it through a QWebView vs. a QTextBrowser.  Not all HTML/CSS functionality exists in a QTextBrowser.  If it looks right in Chrome, it'll probably look right in the WebKit.

Comment: It would surely work, but wouldn't that be an overkill? Thank you for your answer.